# Symfony 2: Return a form in controller

Tags: forms, symfony, controller

Is it possible to return a form via controller, like so:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new TfQuestionType(),$TfQuestion);
    return new Response($form->createView());
```

I would like to retrieve it via Ajax and I know that you are supposed to return a HTML string of the form, but I can't do it in my case.

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this  by rendering a template with `renderView` and returning that as a response. Have a look at the documentation here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates

**EDIT**

In your controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TfQuestionType(), $TfQuestion);

return $this->render(
    'FooBundle:Bar:form.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form)
);
```

Your `form.html.twig` might look something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('some_route')}}">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello Darragh,
Won't your solution completely change my page? I want to "include" dynamically a piece of form via jQuery like [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data/ "Here"). i am currently working on the jQuery ^^

Comment: Hi Gingi. Based on your post, my understanding is that you want to make an AJAX call from the browser to the server that renders a form and returns the HTML response. I assume you will then insert it into the page with JavaScript? If so, then you would add the above code in its own method, for example `QuestionController::ajaxFormAction()` and call that method from the browser. let me know if I'm missing anything and I can amend my answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right Darragh. My initial question was, if I create a method in in my "Question" controller, will I need to return an instance of "Response". I might be wrong but I think that Response only accepts strings as a parameter. With your answer and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516412/load-view-using-ajax-symfony2) I've figured out that I don't necessarily need to use Response() with Ajax in Symfony (most of what I've seen on the web returned a string to create new form inputs).
Thank you very much for your help Darragh . I'll get back to you when it works ^^

Comment: Finally got back home and implemented it, it works fine. Thank you very much!